# Scaling a function by a complex number

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, area

Suppose $f(T)$ is the image of a closed complex set $T$ where $f:\mathbf{C} \rightarrow \mathbf{C}$. How does scaling $f$ by $c\in\mathbf{C}$ affect the area of $f(T)$?

Comment: If it is scaling like this $c\cdot f$, then $c\cdot f(T)$ got rotated by $\operatorname{Arg}(c)$ and expanded by $|c|$.

Comment: Does that mean the area would be expanded by $|c|$ as well, i.e., area($cf(T)$) = $c\times$area($f(T)$) ?

Comment: When you expand a rectangle $[x_1,x_2]\times[y_1,y_2]$ by $|c|$, you get $[|c|x_1,|c|x_2]\times[|c|y_1,|c|y_2]$. Its area went from $|x_2-x_1|\cdot|y_2-y_1|$ to $|c|^2|x_2-x_1|\cdot|y_2-y_1|$. This implies that areas get multiplied by $|c|^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling by $c$ results in multiplying the area by $|c|^2$.